# Using "Cast Service" in an electrons-js app

Tags: javascript, electron, chromium

I would like to know if there is an API that can access the "cast service" from google chrome.

[image: 1] [image: 2].

Comment: Never tried it but there is this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-chromecast and https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:chromecast